# Get object name from list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have something that looks like this:

```
const Books = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
  {'name': 'The book 1', 'price': 30},
  {'name': 'The book 2', 'price': 50},
];
const Newspapper = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
  {'name': 'The Newspapper 1', 'price': 4},
  {'name': 'The Newspapper 2', 'price': 9},
];
```

What's the best way so I can call the name of the variable? It's even possible to print the variable name?
For example, print('you are reading $booksvariable') // you are reading books

also tried with something simmilar

```
const allList = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
  {
    "books": [
  {'name': 'The book 1', 'price': 30},
  {'name': 'The book 2', 'price': 50},
    ]
  },
   {
    "newspapper": [
   {'name': 'The Newspapper 1', 'price': 4},
  {'name': 'The Newspapper 2', 'price': 9},
    ]
  }
];
```

But still can't manage to disnplay only the "books" and "newspapper".

Comment: Hello thanks for you time, but what I was looking to achieve was to print really the var as a string. For example "books" not the elements itself!

Answer (score 1):

```
print(books); //you are reading [{name: The book 1, price: 30}, {name: The book 2, price: 50}]
print(books[1]); //you are reading {name: The book 2, price: 50}
print(allList); //you are reading [{books: [{name: The book 1, price: 30}, {name: The book 2, price: 50}]}, {newspapper: [{name: The Newspapper 1, price: 4}, {name: The Newspapper 2, price: 9}]}]


books.map((e) => print('you are reading ${e['name']}')).toList(); //you are reading The book 1   \n    you are reading The book 2

allList.elementAt(0).map((key, value) {
  print(value); //  [{books: [{name: The book 1, price: 30}, {name: The book 2, price: 50}]}, {newspapper: [{name: The Newspapper 1, price: 4}, {name: The Newspapper 2, price: 9}]}]
  return MapEntry(key, value);
});

books.forEach((element) {
  print('you are reading ${element['name']}'); //you are reading The book 1  \n you are reading The book 1
});
```

Comment: Hello thanks for you time, but what I was looking to achieve was to print really the var as a string. For example "books" not the elements itself!

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to combine the two `Lists` and just print out the name this will suffice:

```dart
const Books = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
  {'name': 'The book 1', 'price': 30},
  {'name': 'The book 2', 'price': 50},
];
const Newspapper = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
  {'name': 'The Newspapper 1', 'price': 4},
  {'name': 'The Newspapper 2', 'price': 9},
];

// Combine the two lists
var combinedList = [];
combinedList.addAll(Books);
combinedList.addAll(Newspapper);

// Get the names by mapping them and print them
var names = combinedList.map((b) => b['name']);
names.forEach((name) {
  print("You are reading $name");
});
```

Output:

```
I/flutter (20249): You are reading The book 1
I/flutter (20249): You are reading The book 2
I/flutter (20249): You are reading The Newspapper 1
I/flutter (20249): You are reading The Newspapper 2
```

---

If you want to print those two seperately you can do this:

```dart
const Books = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
  {'name': 'The book 1', 'price': 30},
  {'name': 'The book 2', 'price': 50},
];
const Newspapper = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
  {'name': 'The Newspapper 1', 'price': 4},
  {'name': 'The Newspapper 2', 'price': 9},
];

// Get the names and print them
Books.forEach((book) {
  print("You are reading the book ${book['name']}");
});

Newspapper.forEach((newspapper) {
  print("You are reading the newpaper ${newspapper['name']}");
});
```

Output:

```
I/flutter (20249): You are reading the book The book 1
I/flutter (20249): You are reading the book The book 2
I/flutter (20249): You are reading the newpaper The Newspapper 1
I/flutter (20249): You are reading the newpaper The Newspapper 2
```

It is up to you if you want to `map` the name first (like in the first example) or just access the name directly in the loop (like `${book['name']}` in the second example). Hope I could help.

---

OP stated that he really wants to print the name of the variable.
In general I would just harcode `"Books"` and print that. If you want to save it in a variable. I **strongly advice against** extracting the actual name of the variable `Books`.

In your example you are actually breaking Flutter conventions. Variables should not start with uppercase. So you should rename your variable to `books` anyways. And what if the variable name changes to something else? You probably still want to print `"Books"`. Those are only a few examples of why not to extract the actual variable name. In 99% of all cases it is bad practice. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Hello thanks for you time, but what I was looking to achieve was to print really the var as a string. For example "books" not the elements itself!

Comment: @Miguel I have edited my answer. There are hacks to extract the variable name. But they are just that: hacks. I do not think that you need them. Just hardcode your string.

Comment: You might want to do `allList.keys.foreach(print);` and make sure allList is a `Map` and not `List` so remove the square brackets around it

Comment: @beckzile that would work as well but you would achieve the same thing as my example so OP can choose whatever he likes best.

Comment: @JosipDomazet you're right. They should instead create a separate model which would be much more easier to handle